# Service is stopped automatically on closing application

Tags: android

I am using a `Service` in my android application for getting location updates continuously through `Fused Location Provider` even when my application is not running. But the problem is that the `Service` is running as long as my application is running and when I close my application `Service` is also stopped after sometime. So please help?

**Starting Service**

```
Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationDetector.class);
startService(startServiceIntent);
```

**Service Code:**

```
package com.example.jahanzebahmed.smartlocator;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;



public class LocationDetector extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    static String lat=null, lon=null;
    static boolean enableNotifications = false;
    static boolean enableEmails = false;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        enableNotifications = true;
        if(!MainActivity.notifications_switch.isChecked())
            MainActivity.notifications_switch.setChecked(true);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }


    synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); // Update location every se
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
        if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            lon = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        checkForNotification();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        checkForNotification();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        enableEmails = false;
        enableNotifications = false;
        stopSelf();
    }


    void checkForNotification() {
        Location location = new Location("fused");
        location.setLatitude(new Double(lat));
        location.setLongitude(new Double(lon));
        if(enableNotifications)
            new CheckReminders(getApplicationContext()).execute(location);
        if(enableEmails)
            new EmailsHandler(getApplicationContext()).execute(location);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

}
```

Comment: first thing is, that the service could be killed by a task manager (external app or system app). In that case, you have to manually protect this app inside this task manager. There is no way to do it programmatically, so you have to inform your user. To keep your service alive, you can return START_STICKY which recreates the service if killed, if resources are free (or as soon as). You can also start your service as a foreground service (what is only recommended in special cases because of battery drain).

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Should i use `AlarmManager` instead of `Service`?

Comment: @SajalAli,return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;  This line is closing the service on close of application.

Comment: wether you can return START_STICKY in your service onStartCommand(), or you can do a foreground service, and also, you can use an alarmManager. But also alarmManager is not guaranteed to live all the time (but resists if you close the app usually).

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

```
public class LocationUpdate extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "SERVICE CLASS";
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
// A request to connect to Location Services
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private LocationListener locationListener;
//public  MapsActivity mapsActivity;

public static String latitude;
public static String longitute;
public static String s;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION = 2;

private static double kph = 3.6;
private double speed = 0.0;

/*public LocationUpdate(MapsActivity mapsActivity) {
    this.mapsActivity=mapsActivity;
}*/

private class LocationListener implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longitute = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        Log.d("location lat",location.getLatitude()+"");
        Log.d("location long",location.getLongitude()+"");
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //  Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    boolean stopService = false;
    if (intent != null)
        stopService = intent.getBooleanExtra("stopservice", false);

    System.out.println("stopservice " + stopService);

    locationListener = new LocationListener();
    if (stopService)
        stopLocationUpdates();
    else {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    //  Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //  Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationListener);
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(3000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    startLocationUpates();
}

private Location startLocationUpates() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    } else {
        // Locatiossssssssn permission has been granted, continue as usual.
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, locationListener);
        //  Log.i("update location","Start update location"+myLocation.getLongitude());
    }
    s = String.valueOf(LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient));

    return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

this will still update the location when the app close.